# Initialize a new instance of the class through its method

Tags: c#, class, initialization

Got this class with lots of properties. There`s constructor which sets properties to its default values and Clear method. (Clear method here is just an example)

```
public class Person
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
    ...
    public string Z;

    public Person()
    {
        this.A = "Default value for A";
        this.B = "Default value for B";
        this.C = "Default value for C";
        ...
        this.Z = "Default value for Z";
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this = new Person(); // Something like this ???
    }
}
```

How can I reinitialize class through Clear method?

I mean:

```
Person p = new Person();

p.A = "Smething goes here for A";
p.B = "Smething goes here for B";
...
// Here do stuff with p
...

p.Clear(); // Here I would like to reinitialize p through the Clear() instead of use p = new Person();
```

I know I could write a function with all the default values settings and use it in constructor and in Clear method. But... is there a "proper" way instead of workarounds?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason, why are you trying reuse the instance?

Comment: avoid memory allocation I guess : which is quite a noble purpose :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather implement `initializer`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
    ...
    public string Z;

    private void Ininialize() {
      this.A = "Default value for A";
      this.B = "Default value for B";
      this.C = "Default value for C";
      ...
      this.Z = "Default value for Z";
    }

    public Person()
    {
       Ininialize();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
       Ininialize();
    }
}
```

....

```
Person p = new Person();
...
p.A = "Something goes here for A";
p.B = "Something goes here for B";
...
p.Clear(); // <- return A, B..Z properties to their default values
```

Comment: Yes... or put Initialize code into Clear method and directly call Clear from constructor : you would avoid one function (which is not a big deal, I agree)

Comment: @Kek: I'd rather separate Initialize() and Clear(): often you have to do something additional on Clear(): e.g. ask a permission, invoke an event(s), say "Clearing" and "Cleared" etc.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for anwser. Basically if I rename Initialize to **SomethingElse** then it`s just what i said earlier :) I could write function and use it in constructor and Clear method. I was just **curious** if there`s "intended way"; like **this** in parameters or so..

Comment: @majk86: In good old times (Delphi, C++), when "this" was just a pointer you could have done some pretty tricks with it; but now in managed .Net environment we can't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want , but I would do it like this :

```
   public class Person
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
    ...
    public string Z;

    public Person()
    {
        ResetToDefault();
    }

    public void ResetToDefault()
    {
        this.A = "Default value for A";
        this.B = "Default value for B";
        this.C = "Default value for C";
        ...
        this.Z = "Default value for Z";
    }
}
```

well , at some point you must give the parameters their values.

When you want to reset it to default.. just do this :

```
Person person = new Person();
//do your stuff here .....
//when reset it:
person.ResetToDefault();
```

Comment: Basically same as Dmitry wrote.. but thanks anyway :)